# Does $ f(pq)\times f((1-p)(1-q))=f(p(1-q))\times f(q(1-p))$ imply $f(pq)=f(p)\times f(q)$ over $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

Let $f(x)$ be a non-negative Lebesgue measurable (or continuous, or differentiable, or strictly monotone, as needed) function defined on $[0,1]$.

**Condition A**: $f(x)$ satisfies
$$ f(pq)\times f((1-p)(1-q))=f(p(1-q))\times f(q(1-p))$$ for all $p,q\in [0,1]$.

**Condition B**: $f(x)$ satisfies
$$ f(pq)=k \times f(p)\times f(q)$$ where $k$ is a constant, for all $p,q\in [0,1]$.

**Condition B** obviously implies **Condition A**.

Question: Does **Condition A** imply **Condition B**?

Answer (score 1):

No: $f(x)=2x$ satisfies Condition A but not Condition B.

Condition A is a homogeneous identity (both sides are the product of the same number of $f$-values), while Condition B is a non-homogeneous identity (the two sides are products of different numbers of $f$-values). Therefore even if one function $f$ satisfies both conditions, then any nontrivial multiple of $f$ will still satisfy Condition A but will no longer satisfy Condition B.

Edited to add: $f(x)=x^2$ also satisfies Condition A but not the new Condition B when $k\ne0,1$. Homogeneity also means that we can raise a solution to a power and get a new solution.

Comment: You are right. But I misstated my Condition B. My bad! See edited Condition B.

Comment: Still not enough :) see edited answer

Comment: Dear Greg, in the case of $f(x)=2x$, $f(xy)=2xy=(1/2)2x2y=(1/2)f(x)f(y)$ - Condition B.

Comment: A known fact is: Condition B is true if and only if $f(x)=\lambda x^\alpha$ for some constants $\lambda$ and $\alpha$.